# What do you call this kind of sorting in JAVA?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Hope that you guys are having a good day!

I'm new to Java so I'm still getting the hang of it.

There is a sorting algorithm which I do use more often than not

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    for(int j=i; j<array.length; j++){
        if(array[j] < array[i]){
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:
The outer loop first use the first element of the array and start comparing that to the rest of the elements inside the list, if it is larger than one of the element, swap it.

For example, we got an array 12, 5, 14, 8, 3

We have array[0] as 12.
Comparing that to array[1] in the inner loop, since 5<12 we swap them. The inner loop continues until array[4] where array[4] < array[0]
now we have 3 as the smallest element in the array in the right place

Rinse and repeat with the rest of the elements

What is this type of sorting? Because it doesn't seem to fit in Selection Sort or Insertion Sort let alone Bubble Sort.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm? Or from where you have it? It's cumbersome to read through the algorithm to understand it if you could just explain it to us.

Comment: It's selection sort.  You start at index `0` and find the smallest element in the array and put it at index `0`.  Then you go to index `1` and do the same thing, and so on until the last index.

Comment: Why do you think this is not selection sort? It does some unnecessary iterations, but it's selection sort

Comment: This is not bubble sort. Bubble sort will be comparing j to j - 1 instead of i. https://www.javatpoint.com/bubble-sort-in-java

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I did make someone misunderstand something in the code

Comment: You can cut the number of iterations in half by changing your inner loop to `for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++)`. There's no reason to check items `1` through `i` in that loop, because you know they're already in the proper order.

Comment: It's called selection sort because at each iteration of the outer loop, you're *selecting* the i-th smallest number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: It type of sorting is selection sorting.
View here[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/]

Comment: Thanks to those who enlightened me with such explanation!

Comment: [GeeksforGeeks describes selection sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/) as *repeatedly finding the minimum element (considering ascending order) from unsorted part and putting it at the beginning*. Many more swaps my happen with the procedure presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most definitely selection sort since at the end you're swapping a higher number near the beginning for a lower number further away. Most of the time if a sort method has a swap at the end it's selection.

Comment: It is most definitely **not** a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)! It is most definitely a (kind of) [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: It would have been selection sort if it *did* swap in the end, only. But the procedure presented swaps with each and every remaining element if those are in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *kind of* [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). A bubble sort would compare `array[j-1]` with `array[j]`, not `array[i]` with `array[j]`, but the overall effect is similar: The algorithm moves *all* larger elements to the right simultaneously, whereas a bubble sort moves each element in turn to the right until a larger element is encountered.

It is *not* a selection sort, which starting at index 0, finds the smallest element from index onwards then swaps it with the element at index, then increments index and repeats for all indexes.

Your code is a java implementation of a simplified and unoptimized version of this [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation).

Comment: Note how en.wikipedia states `Bubble sort […] compares adjacent elements and swaps them [where necessary]`. I think [RBKreckel's contribution to "the Talk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Bubble_sort#Sinking_sort) is right - at least, this is *not* bubble sort (where values "bubble up" like gas bubbles in fluids).

Comment: @greybeard OK, I see. Cool. Answer modified to reflect this insight.

Comment: (If you want to be irritated if everybody overlooked where `j` starts, have a look at [What is this odd sorting algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).)